# Django - Form validation, clean method for both hidden and visible fields

Tags: python, django, forms, hidden-field

I am trying to validate fields, one visible filled by the user, and an other one: hidden for the user but filled by the template.

Here is my form:

```
class AForm(forms.Form):

    xxxx = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    yyyy = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    def clean(self):

        xxxx=self.cleaned_data['xxxx']
        yyyy=self.cleaned_data['yyyy']              ##ERROR
        if function_check(xxxx,yyyy)==False:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Try again!")

        return xxxx
```

In my template I have:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.xxxx}}
    <input id="id_yyyy" name="yyyy" type="hidden" value='{{ code_generated_value }}' maxlength="30">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The only error I get is :   'yyyy' at the `yyyy=self.cleaned_data['yyyy']` line.

I found this question: [Hidden field in Django form not in cleaned_data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8328763/3425402)

But it was not very helping.

**EDIT 1:** Generated HTML code

```
   <p><input id="id_xxxx" maxlength="30" name="xxxx" type="text" /></p>
   <input id="id_yyyy" maxlength="30" name="yyyy" type="hidden" value='97a8eee9477b73dda401b15369f8db00a0d6ab79.png'>
   <input type="submit"/>
```

Comment: Are you certain that `code_generated_value` returns something? You could also try to get the value using `yyyy=self.cleaned_data.get('yyyy')` instead of `yyyy=self.cleaned_data['yyyy']`

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Also, why do you have this `return xxxx`? It shouldn't be there on class level.

Comment: @nnaelle, yes I am sure that `code_generated_value` returns something. I tried  `yyyy=self.cleaned_data.get('yyyy')` as you suggest, but yyyy is empty.

Comment: @AlexShkop, I get only the error indicated at the end of my question. I corrected my indentation mistake: It was good in my code but wrong in Stackoverflow, thanks ;)

Comment: Pls, post the whole stack trace and exception class.

Comment: BTW, `clean` method shouldn't return anything.

Comment: Post generated HTML please :)

Comment: Pls, show how you create and use `AForm` object in your view function.

Comment: @Anpher, done! By the way, thanks to you, I just realized that my code_generated_value is way longer than 30 characters! Maybe that is THE problem ?

Comment: @Anpher You nailed it ;) The length of the `code_generated_value` was over 30 characters, now it's good! Can you please make an answer that I can approve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check generated HTML and POST data for request. You will see any fields missing & stuff. Also, use `.get(field_name)` method.

[Check here for more.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#django.forms.Form.clean) How to properly access `cleaned_data` from `super`, etc.